# Sort by field, then sort that list by another field, then sum the last field and keeping the previous sorts

Tags: sorting, sum, field

I am processing a very long list of events, can be in the thousands of lines.
Final got it down into this format.

sw_port:3:3:1 WWN 29325002ac0256b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 5
sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac0856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 5
sw_port:3:3:3 WWN 29325002ac0886b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 87
sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac0856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 9
sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac2856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 9

I want to sum the total events and used the following    awk '{sum+=$9}END{print sum}'
I got this output:
Port sw_port:3:3:2,      WWN 29325002ac0856b3,   Sum 10264

Then I realized that is not exactly what I needed.
I need to sort first by sw_port:?:?:?
Then do another sort on the 3rd field.
Finally sum the 9th field.

So the output is like this

sw_port:3:3:1 WWN 29325002ac0256b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 5

sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac0856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 14

sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac2856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 9

sw_port:3:3:3 WWN 29325002ac0886b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 87

So since the sw_port and WWN were the same for

sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac0856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 5

and

sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac0856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 9

I want to see this   (5 + 9 = 14) so

sw_port:3:3:2 WWN 29325002ac0856b3 Invalid CRC Count changed by 14

Tried various things like sort -k1,1n -k3,3n and that seems to sort the two fields I want.

If I try to sort on field 9 I get the total of all field 9.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on to the answer:

awk '{array[$1","$3]+=$9} END { for (i in array) {print i"," array[i]}}' | sort

sw_port:0:4:1,10001c98ec09308e,26
sw_port:0:4:1,10001c98ec095076,7
sw_port:0:4:2,20420002ac0256b3,5485